# radare2 how to interpret ascii-art color bars?

Tags: radare2

I can't understand the meaning of ascii-art color bars.
what is the meaning of the `#` charaters?

```
[0x08000210]> iS=
00  0x08000000 |---------------------------------| 0x08000000     0 ---      
01  0x08000200 |--------------------#------------| 0x0800020d    13 rw-  .data
02* 0x08000210 |---------------------##----------| 0x08000237    39 r-x  .text
03  0x08000240 |-----------------------###-------| 0x08000272    50 ---  .shstrtab
04  0x08000280 |-------------------------#######-| 0x08000310   144 ---  .symtab
05  0x08000310 |-------------------------------##| 0x0800032a    26 ---  .strtab
06  0x08000330 |--------------------------------#| 0x08000348    24 ---  .rela.text
07  0x08000000 |###------------------------------| 0x08000040    64 rw-  ehdr
=>  0x08000210 |---------------------------------| 0x0800020f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This chart describes the different Sections and Memory Segments in your binary.

Each row in the chart is a different section where its name is in the rightest column. From the left, you can see its start address, from the right you can see its end-address and next to it you can see the sections' size (decimal). That means, `Start-Address + Size = End-Address`.

The ASCII bar itself is an imaginary range of addresses and the hash sign `#` will mark where on this range the section appears. In your example, the chart begins at `0x08000000` which is the lowest address and ends at `0x08000348` which is the highest. The `.symtab` is the biggest section in your example since it in size of 144. This is why it has the biggest amount of `#` characters.